# How to clear out element inside an array?

Tags: c++

I want to clear out all the element inside my array but I don't know how to automatically clear it out. is there a function for it? Like the clear() for lists??

```
int array[5] = {2,5,4,8,6};
```

then I want to clear out everything and add a new set of values

Comment: What do you mean by clear out?  Elements cannot be removed from an array so even if you are not using it it will still have some value in it.

Comment: what do you mean with "clear out"? An array has a fixed number of elements, thus you cannot erase elements.

Comment: Just put the new values there. No need to clear. However, if you use `std::array` then you can probably just assign `{}`.

Comment: If you want an array from which you can remove elements, perhaps you should be using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: I mean, there is std::fill if you just want to set all the elements to 0 or to some other value. It won't resize the array though.

Answer (score 5):

Your question isn't valid because you **can't `clear out`** an array. An array has a fixed size and there always will be some value in it.

If you want to re-use an array, just overwrite the existing values.

Perhaps consider using `std::vector`. Using `clear()` function, you can clear all the values from the `std::vector`.

Learn about `std::vector` [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 0):

To clear an array means to set all values to T() that for arrays of fundamental arithmetic types is equivalent to set all elements to zeroes.

You can do it in several ways. The first one is to use standard C function `std::memset` declared in header `<cstring>`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    int array[] = { 2, 5, 4, 8, 6 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );

    for ( int x : array ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::memset( array, 0, N * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( int x : array ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Another way is to use standard algorithm `std::fill` declared in header `<algorithm>`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    int array[] = { 2, 5, 4, 8, 6 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );

    for ( int x : array ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::fill( array, array + N, 0 );

    for ( int x : array ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the both cases the program output is

```
2 5 4 8 6 
0 0 0 0 0
```

If you need a variable length array then use standard container `std::vector<int>`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> array = { 2, 5, 4, 8, 6 };

    for ( int x : array ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    array.clear();

    std::cout << "array is empty - " << std::boolalpha << array.empty() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 5 4 8 6 
array is empty - true
```

Instead of `array.clear();` there could be also used `array.resize( 0 );` in the program.